# Data Cleaning Binary to Categorical

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I'm having difficulty using ifelse to create a new column. I want the original columns that I'm using that either have 1, 0, or na to become more of a categorical variable in the new column. For example, in the new column I have 9 categories that I want to include in the new column.

```
products_at_six <- quitting_30day_cleaning %>%
  mutate(products_after_six = ifelse(products6___1 == 1, 1, 0,
                              ifelse(products6___2 == 1, 2, 0,
                              ifelse(products6___3 == 1, 3, 0,
                              ifelse(products6___4 == 1, 4, 0,
                              ifelse(products6___5 == 1, 5, 0,
                              ifelse(products6___6 == 1, 6, 0,
                              ifelse(products6___7 == 1, 7, 0,
                              ifelse(products6___8 == 1, 8, 0,
                              ifelse(products6___9 == 1, 9, 0))))))))))
```

This is what I tried but I get an error that states:

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `products_after_six = ifelse(...)`.
Caused by error in `ifelse()`:
! unused argument (ifelse(products6___2 == 1, 2, 0, ifelse(products6___3 == 1, 3, 0, ifelse(products6___4 == 1, 4, 0, ifelse(products6___5 == 1, 5, 0, ifelse(products6___6 == 1, 6, 0, ifelse(products6___7 == 1, 7, 0, ifelse(products6___8 == 1, 8, 0, ifelse(products6___9 == 1, 9, 0)))))))))
Backtrace:

1. quitting_30day_cleaning %>% ...
2. dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
3. dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
4. dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
5. mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
6. dplyr (local) eval()

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using `case_when` instead?

```
products_at_six <- quitting_30day_cleaning %>%
  mutate(products_after_six = case_when(products6___1 == 1 ~ 1,
                                        products6___2 == 1 ~ 2,
                                        products6___3 == 1 ~ 3,
                                        products6___4 == 1 ~ 4,
                                        products6___5 == 1 ~ 5,
                                        products6___6 == 1 ~ 6,
                                        products6___7 == 1 ~ 7,
                                        products6___8 == 1 ~ 8,
                                        products6___9 == 1 ~ 9))
```

Comment: Did it work????